# What's "s" mean in result of `ls -l`?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm running `ls -l`, result is

```
[root@yf-mos-test-net09 b2cebb02-d171-4929-95d6-61e54cd647f7]# ls /usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/n-ddc979cd -l
srwxr-x--- 1 root root 0 Jun  8 15:53 /usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/n-ddc979cd
```

what's "s" mean in "srwxr-x---" ?

Thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @PS. To be fair, on my system, `man ls` doesn't explain anything about the output - looks like `info ls` does though.

Answer (score 1):

The first letter is for file type. The 's' means it's a socket.